# JBOSS not starting from cmd

Tags: java, jboss, cmd

I have JBOSS installed in my Windows 7 machine., I can start JBOSS from Eclipse but it doesn't publish and when I try to run the standalone.bat file from the Bin directory it throws this error ,

```
  JAVA_OPTS: -client -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat **-Xms1303M -Xmx1303M** -XX:MaxPe
rmSize=256M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInter
val=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -D
jboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standa
lone.xml

**Error occurred during initialization of VM**
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
```

I did research the forum and many are suggesting to change the -Xms1303M to -Xms256M ., I edited the standalone.conf file in an editor but it is not getting reflected and getting the same error again.

Could someone please guide me ?

Comment: there is a setClasspath.bat, set the xms and the xmx in that particular file.

Comment: I don't have a setClasspath.bat file., but I was doing the changes in standalone.conf file., Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using? The suggestion you found in the forum you mention looks right, at the beginning decrease both paramters: -Xms256M and -Xmx256M, you can even try to decrease the -XX:MaxPermSize=128M. And be sure that you have enough memory/swap in the machine. Of course if you need to deploy big applications you'll have to increase these parameters (and even maybe the memory/swap of your system).

Answer (score 7):

Most likely, you are using or running jboss on a 32 bit jdk and the memory params are out of range or exceed the limits of a 32 bit jdk. Either upgrade to a 64 bit jdk or add this line in your run.conf in jboss/bin, remove the jvm args from your command line and see if jboss starts.

set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms128M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, it is the standalone.bat file and not the standalone.conf file that must be modified with the new `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable.